# Cppcheck can't check the third parameters?

Tags: c++, cppcheck

Here is my .cfg

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<def format="1">
  <function name="wcscpy_s">
        <arg nr="1">
            <not-uninit/>
        </arg>
        <arg nr="2">
            <not-uninit/>
        </arg>
        <arg nr="3">
            <not-uninit/>
        </arg>
    </function>
</def>
```

And I use it to check blow cpp file.

```
int main() {
    char a[100];
    wcscpy_s(
        a,
        a,
        a);
}
```

And the error is:

```
D:\staff>cppcheck D:\staff\test.cpp --library=my.cfg
Checking D:\staff\test.cpp...
[D:\staff\test.cpp:4]: (error) Uninitialized variable: a
[D:\staff\test.cpp:5]: (error) Uninitialized variable: a
```

Obviously it not find the third parameter， it is unitialized too.
I changed the file to this:

```
int main() {
    char a[100];
    wcscpy_s(
        1,
        1,
        a);
}
```

And it not show any error now.
So I'm very confused.
Cppcheck can't check the third parameters?

Comment: Oh my god, who thought it's a good idea to describe C++ functions using XML?

Comment: it's imo great that Cppcheck knows how functions work. xml is a format that has quite good tool support.

Comment: I think you agree it's good Cppcheck knows how functions work. So how could we configure how wcscpy_s work. I don't think there are many alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's not by intention. I think it's caused by some old code that was only meant to handle some special functions.

Can you create a ticket about this?
http://trac.cppcheck.net/

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Cppcheck (1.70 dev) is able to detect this issue:

```
$ cppcheck test.cpp  --library=my.cfg
Checking test.cpp...
[test.cpp:4]: (error) Uninitialized variable: a
[test.cpp:5]: (error) Uninitialized variable: a
[test.cpp:6]: (error) Uninitialized variable: a
```